Docker compose virtual environment broken
I'm working on a FastAPI project in VSCode and encountering a persistent issue where my imports for FastAPI are not being recognized (Import "fastapi" could not be resolved).
A problem occurs and after deleting all containers and images, fastapi cannot be imported when entering main.py in the host environment regardless of docker. (Fast API operates in the host environment before docker-compose up --build)
Additionally, when I try to use pip in the terminal within VSCode, I get a zsh: command not found: pip error.
When I enter docker compose run web
I got an error:
The virtual environment found in /app/.venv seems to be broken.

Recreating virtualenv untitled folder 2 in /app/.venv.

Under are my codes.
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN pip install poetry

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* /app/

RUN poetry config --list

RUN poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

COPY . /app

CMD ["poetry", "run", "uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "123"}


I have tried resetting the virtual environment and manually setting the Python interpreter in VSCode, but the issue persists.

I tried various modifications to dockerfile and dockercompose. but no effect.

Changing environment variables in .zshrc and python version of brew, no effect.



Any solutions ?

You are probably copying your own .venv along with the project and it overwrites the .venv that poetry creates inside the docker image.
The line COPY . /app copies everything from the working directory to docker image, which includes .venv if it exists.
One simple solution would be to remove .venv.
You might also consider copying specific files or directories instead of the whole content of the working directory.
